# Can anybody tell why is it saying, “The named parameter ‘children’ isn’t defined

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

So I’m using flutter for a week now and I got into this error which says “The named parameter ‘children’ isn’t defined. Can anybody review my code and please tell me what is the fix.

Comment: We can't review your code if you don't post it :)

Comment: You need to post the code so we can help you out, based on what you told us it sounds like @jonatas Borges is might be right, what is the widget you're getting the error from?

Answer (score 1):

"children" can only be used within Columns, Rows, Wraps, ListViews and Stacks. The rest of the widgets are not aligned in a chain or overlap, and receive only a single "child".
If you are having to assign a parameter named "children" to a class that it doesn't have (like Container() for example) you will get this error.

If you want your code to be analyzed, you should put it together with your question next time.